# Xcode not importing Supabase libraries correctly

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, authentication, supabase

I'm setting up a Swift iOS application using Supabase for the back-end, but my Xcode is not using correctly the Supabase library. Im trying to implement a Log in for my app, but when I call the Supabase Auth function to authenticate, Xcode says "Module 'Supabase' has no member named 'Auth'".

Keep in mind that im doing `import Supabase` at the start of the Swift file, and I initialize successfully my `SupabaseClient` in the main Swift file. I have the Supabase dependencies installed and Xcode shows them in Package Dependencies.

Here is the piece of code that doesn't work:

```
func logIn(_ email: String, _ password: String) {
        
    do {
        try await supabase.auth.signIn( //  <-- Line that doesn't work
            email: email,
            password: password  
        )
        // Code to execute if signIn is successful
    } catch {
        // Handle the error if signIn throws an exception
        print("Error signing in: \(error)")
    }
        print(email, password)
        print("Autenticated!")
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
func logIn(_ email: String, _ password: String) async {
    do {
        let session = try await supabase.auth.signIn(
            email: email,
            password: password
        )
        print("Sign in successful: \(session)")
    } catch {
        print(email, password)
        print("Error signing in: \(error)")
    }
}
```